# put a list of one post type in other post type to select from it and display selected item in second post type's single page

Tags: custom-post-types, list, select

I have two post types in my website. one for courses and other for teachers. I want to put a selectable list of teachers post type in courses post type and then show it in course single page and link it to single page of that teacher. how can i do?

```
 function custom_meta_box_markup($object)
  {
 wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), "meta-box-nonce");
 ?>
  <div>
  <select name="meta-box-dropdown">
  <?php 
  $args=array('post_type'=>'mama_ashpaz');
  $q=new WP_Query($args);


   if($q->have_posts()){
   $current=0;
     while($q->have_posts()){
       $q->the_post();?>
  <?php $options[$current]=get_the_title();
    $options_id[$current]=get_the_id();
    $current++;

    }

    }wp_reset_postdata();
    foreach($options as $key=>$value){
    if($value == get_post_meta($object->ID, "meta-box-dropdown", true))
     {
     ?>
     <option selected><?php echo $value; ?></option>
    <?php    
     }
    else
    {
     ?>
   <option><?php echo $value; ?></option>
    <?php
    }

   }
    ?>
   </select>
   </div>
   <?php  
  }

   function add_custom_meta_box()
   {
    add_meta_box("demo-meta-box", "مامان آشپز", "custom_meta_box_markup", 
  "product", "side", "high", null);
   }

   add_action("add_meta_boxes", "add_custom_meta_box");



    function save_custom_meta_box($post_id, $post, $update)
    {
    if (!isset($_POST["meta-box-nonce"]) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST["meta- 
    box-nonce"], basename(__FILE__)))
     return $post_id;

      if(!current_user_can("edit_post", $post_id))
      return $post_id;

      if(defined("DOING_AUTOSAVE") && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
       return $post_id;

     $slug = "product";
     if($slug != $post->post_type)
     return $post_id;

    $meta_box_dropdown_value = "";

    if(isset($_POST["meta-box-dropdown"]))
     {
     $meta_box_dropdown_value = $_POST["meta-box-dropdown"];
     }   
    update_post_meta($post_id, "meta-box-dropdown", 
    $meta_box_dropdown_value);

    }

    add_action("save_post", "save_custom_meta_box", 10, 3);

       function add_maman(){?>
     <div class="maman-meta"><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink();?>">
    <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_id(), "meta-box-dropdown", true ) ;?>
    </a>
    </div>
    <?php
     }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary','add_maman' );
```

Comment: To be clear, you are trying to allow the user to select a teacher from the courses EDIT screen? So you can associate a teacher with a course?

Comment: no.. i want to select a teacher for each course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot create a complete solution here, because it's kinda a *'work for me for free'* question.

I can (globally) tell you how to accomplish this.

1. wp-admin --> courses CPT --> add a metabox 'select teacher(s)'. Collect the teachers with `get_posts()`. Save the selected teachers as meta, use `update_post_meta($course_post_id, 'assigned_teachers', $assigned_teachers)` in metabox save function.
2. In courses single page template, collect the assigned teachers with `get_post_meta($course_post_id, 'assigned_teachers', true)`. If you want to get the link to a teacher post use `get_permalink($teacher_post_id)`.

I hope this is enough to get you started.

---

**UPDATE** ( OP added code )

Your first function:

```
function custom_meta_box_markup($object)
 {
wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), "meta-box-nonce");
?>
 <div>
 <select name="meta-box-dropdown">
 <?php
 $args=array('post_type'=>'mama_ashpaz');
 $q=new WP_Query($args);


  if($q->have_posts()){
  $current=0;
    while($q->have_posts()){
      $q->the_post();?>
 <?php $options[$current]=get_the_title();
   $option[$current]=get_the_id();
   $current++;

   }

   }wp_reset_postdata();
   foreach($options as $key=>$value){
   if($value == get_post_meta($object->ID, "meta-box-dropdown", true))
    {
    ?>
    <option selected><?php echo $value; ?></option>
   <?php
    }
   else
   {
    ?>
  <option><?php echo $value; ?></option>
   <?php
   }

  }
   ?>
  </select>
  </div>
  <?php
 }
```

Is kinda messy, and you're not creating the `<option>` correctly.

Make it like this:

```
function custom_meta_box_markup($product)

  $options_html = '';

  $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // get all posts
    'post_type' => 'mama_ashpaz',
  );
  $teacher_posts = get_posts($args);

  $selected_teacher = get_post_meta($product->ID, "selected_teacher", true); // notice the different naming, this is more clear.

  if($teacher_posts) {
    foreach($teacher_posts as $teacher) {

      $selected = '';
      if($teacher->ID == $selected_teacher) $selected = 'selected="selected"';

      // in your code you are not setting the option value.
      // When you save the form and collect it with save_post action hook. Only the 'option value=""' will be passed to the $_POST.
      $options_html .= '<option value="'.$teacher->ID.'" '.$selected.'>'.$teacher->post_title.'</option>';
    }
  }

  // start the Output
  ?>
  <select name="product_teachers_select">
  <?php echo $options_html; ?>
  </select>
  <?php
}

// If you're keeping the above naming, make sure you update the remaining follow-up functions
```

Now the teacher id is saved. When you retrieve the teacher you will have his id. With his id you can collect any data you want, example:

```
$teacher = get_post($teacher_id);
$teacher_description = $teacher->post_content;
$teacher_custom_meta = get_post_meta($teacher->ID, 'the_custom_meta_key', true);
```

> **Tip:**
>   when you create your code, try to name your `params, meta_keys, functions`
>   etc. in a way that anyone can understand what's going on.
>   Even for yourself this is very important (imagine looking at your code 2 years from now).

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: I don't see any code, but nevermind... I think you can better try the answer from @dhirenpatel22. With ACF it's a bit easier to understand everything. And you probably find better guides with Google. Please accept his answer if you go that way. Thanks!

Comment: Hi.. I put my code.. I created dropdown metabaox and print selected option in single page of product.how I can retrive selected option's ID and put it's permalink in single page? thanks for your favour.

Comment: Please understand. I can't see your code from here. It's difficult to tell what to do. When you save the selected teachers, save the id's. When you retrieve the selected teachers you will have their id's, with that you can get any data you want.

Comment: I edited my quesion and put the code. don't see it?

Comment: yeah i see it now. one sec, i'll edit my answer.

Comment: your last code is excellent.. thanks so much.. but now selected item doesn't save in database. and after publishing post and refreshing page, the selected meta return to first item.

Comment: Did you see (and did) the last comment in my code? _"If you're keeping the above naming, make sure you update the remaining follow-up functions"_

Answer (score 0):

You will require a custom meta box with a drop-down field.

Here's [a link](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/). It properly teaches how to use and save the data from the meta box.

On that meta box, you can add **WP_Query** to get the list of your teacher post type. You can set the option value as **ID** which you can use to query on the front end.

On the frontend, you can use the [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function to get the saved value from your dropdown.

Then, use [get_permalink](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) function and pass in the meta value as an argument to get the full permalink of the teacher.

That's it.

Comment: thanks. I created a dropdown metabox from post type in product post type. but how can save selected meta and then print it in single page of product with it's permalink?

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party free WordPress plugin "ACF" to add the additional custom field.

You can add **relationship field** and select post type which you want to display in another post type as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Use below code in the single page to display selected posts.

```
<?php $posts = get_field('relationship_field_name');
if( $posts ): ?>
  <ul>
  <?php foreach( $posts as $p ): // variable must NOT be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $p->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $p->ID ); ?></a>
        <span>Custom field from $post: <?php the_field('author', $p->ID); ?></span>
    </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Find the brief explanation of how to use relationship field in below reference URL: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/

Comment: thanks.. what about Post Object in ACF?.. and i want to print custom meta in single page with it's permalink.

Comment: You can select "Post Objects" as return format when creating relationship custom field in ACF. For permalinks of selected posts, you can use get_permalink, which I have already shown in above code.